# Why I get ConcurrentModificationException even though I am using locks?

Tags: java, concurrency

This is my class:

```
public class AComplicatedclass {
    private List<Connection> activeConnections;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();          

    public void printConnections() {
        lock.lock();
        for(Connection c : activeConnections){ //exception happens here
            ...prints details about connection
            activeConnections.remove(c);
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    private class MyThread extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            lock.lock();
                ...can alter activeConnections....
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see a lock object should prevent problems due to concurrent access to that shared array. Nevertheless, when `printConnections()` method is called, I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` in that `for`.

How come? There is no concurrent modification at all!

Comment: Please show what are you doing into the loop. "do something" is very insteresting

Comment: It is likely that "... do something ..." is adding or removing items in activeConnections.

Comment: And you may want to have a look at [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) to simplify your code.

Comment: sorry, anyway yes I remove the object from that list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably you modify your collection inside the for-loop. As the documentation on [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) states

> For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

The reason an iterator throws the exception is that it can no longer be determined which element is to be returned next.

So if you want to modify your collection you need to either switch to something like [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) or use the [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) explicitly as in

```
    Iterator<Connection> iterator = activeConenctions.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Connection c = iterator.next();
        if(/* what ever */) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Phate with direkt Iterator access? Which concrete List-type are you using? What else are you doing?

Comment: @Phate you need to call `iterator.next()` before you can call `remove()`. Try it as seen here or at Raphaël's. Mixing `Iterator` with `for` on the same `Collection` won't work as Java will always use a new `Iterator` for the `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Editing a list during a foreach iteration almost always results in a ConcurrentModificationException, even if your application is single threaded.

If you need to remove items during the iteration, use an iterator:

```
final Iterator<Connection> iterator = activeConnections.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    final Connection connection = iterator.next();
    // ...prints details about connection
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: That depends on your Collection; see CopyOnWriteArrayList from my answer ;-) (but yes it is the most common thing)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of `ConcurrentModificationException`:

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

This has nothing to do with unsynchronized access.

Some examples of problematic operations:

- the current element of the iteration is removed from the collection, what would be the next element in that case?
- Some element that was already iterated over is removed and re-inserted later in the collection. Should the iterator show it again when it reaches the new position?